# CI/CD pipeline for Logic app (consumption) with parameterized connections

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-logic-apps

I would like to ask if it is possible to deploy LogicApp consumption to azure with parameterized connections,
currently im using task:

```
                - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
                  displayName: "Deploy ARM template"
                  inputs:
                    azureResourceManagerConnection: $(connectionName)
                    subscriptionName: $(subscriptionId)
                    resourceGroupName: $(resourceGroupName)
                    location: $(location)
                    csmFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/armtemplate/**/workflow.json
                    csmParametersFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/armtemplate/**/parameters.json
                    deploymentMode: "Incremental"
                    overrideParameters: -subscriptionId $(subscriptionId) -resourceGroupName $(resourceGroupName) -location $(locationParameter)
```

this task deploy my logic app correctly, but there are no parameters
my workflow.json looks like this:
[image]
Im getting this kind of error:
#[error]LinkedAuthorizationFailed: The client has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/connections/join/action' on scope '/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/LogicAppTestDeploy2', however the linked subscription '[parameters('subscriptionId')]' was not found.

Am i doing something wrong? or is it even possible to make connections parameterized?

thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARM template is referencing an API Connection resource called "sharepointonline-01" which should exist beforehand, you could also deploy it alongside the Logic App workflow
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/connections?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template).

You are getting this error because your parameterized string "id" is not valid ARM. To get the desired result you can use the **concat** function instead.

But, since you are referencing an existing resource, use one of the resource functions available in ARM for referencing resources:(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#subscriptionresourceid)

To get something like this:

```
"sharepointonline": {
   "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', 'sharepointonline-1')]",
   "id": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis', parameters('location'), 'sharepointonline')]",
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @swierc,
i tried your approach with usage of subscriptionResourceId and resourceId and it worked!
I also tried to parametrize sharepointonline-1, but that didn't worked. is it even possible?
my code:
`"sharepointonline": {"connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('connectionName'))]","connectionName": "[parameters('connectionName')]","id": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis', parameters('location'), 'sharepointonline')]" }`

Comment: I am not sure if you can define the connection name like that in the connection reference. This reference assumes it already exists. If you want to create the connection with custom name you should add it as a separate resource in the ARM template. Then you can set the name of the API connection and use it in the workflow template

Comment: Edit - I just tried it again and find out that you were right, It's vice versa -> connectionId can contain parametrized connection, but connectionName could not, could this be done somehow when we know that connection will exists under some name?